# JPA Embeddables - The Entity class C has an embedded attribute [x] of type T which is NOT an Embeddable class

Tags: java, jpa

I found an effective (and pretty simple solution) to my problem but I'm curious about the concepts.

I was getting Exceptions trying to embed a class (Wallet) inside another class (User).

User

```java
public class User {
    @Id
    String username;
    String password;
    String hint;
    String answer;
    String email;
    @Embedded
    Wallet wallet;
...
```

Wallet

```java
@Embeddable
public class Wallet {
    double balance;
    PrivateKey privatekey;
    PublicKey publickey;
    String address;
```

Main method to create both the user record and the DB itself, so I can run experimental code, start doing login authentication, etc.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UserService().addUserService(new User("zelda", "ganon", "powerwisdom", "love", "zelda@hyrule.hr", new Wallet()));
    }
```

This gave me errors about Wallet not being an embeddable class. Why is that? Is it because PublicKey and PrivateKey don't allow embedding? If so, how would they do that?

I know it might not be smart in the real world to embed a wallet with all this information in a database. Would that work logistically first of all? I know it might throw illegal reflective access error, which I would want to avoid but for a quick and dirty way, should this not work and be very conveient?

As concerns security, how does this approach work for a basic/average level security requirement where public and private keys are concerned? Can you store this stuff togehter in a database or is it a big no no (assuming the db itself has tight controls)?

What would be the best way to store this info that's not too complicated?

Btw my solution was

```java
@Embeddable
public class WalletForDB {

    byte[] publickey;
    byte[] privatekey;
    double balance;
    String address;

    public WalletForDB(Wallet wallet) {
        super();
        this.publickey = wallet.getPublickey().getEncoded();
        this.privatekey = wallet.getPrivatekey().getEncoded();
        this.address = wallet.getAddress();
        this.balance = wallet.getBalance();
    }
```

And you can fill in the blanks, and it works as expected

Comment: To embed the public/private key in your `Embeddable`, take a look at the `AttributeConverter`, in the [Javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) and the specifications. It's quite straight-forward. If converting from `byte[]` to the object representation of the keys is expensive, you could do it lazily in the getters and setters and cache the key objects in JPA `@Transient` fields.